# Why does the MultiBinding not work for CornerRadius

Tags: wpf, multibinding, cornerradius

If i use an `IValueConverter` it works, while with an `IMultiValueConverter` returning the same value it does not, why is that?

```
<Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"
        CornerRadius="{Binding Converter={vc:SingleAndMultiConverter}}" />
<Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"
        CornerRadius="{MultiBinding Converter={vc:SingleAndMultiConverter}}" />
```

```
public class SingleAndMultiConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert();
    }
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert();
    }
    private object Convert()
    {
        return 15;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The multi-binding throws this error:

> Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='15'

Comment: You are doing something wrong but are not showing us any relevant code...

Comment: hey sir,this is almost all my code.
ok, if you want to read the code generate by the ide.

Comment: and now , could you help me out of this trouble?

Comment: No, because you did not even explain ***how*** it does not work.

Comment: @H.B. you could load it and see that it is throwing an error.  Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='15'.  What I think is going on is the Multi is returning a string.  But [ValueConversion(typeof(object[]),typeof(double))] did not fix it.

Comment: @BalamBalam: The `ValueConversionAttribute` does **nothing** it's just a decoration which tells anyone using the converter what the convert method is *supposed to do*. Also you should have included the bloody error in your question, instead of saying "it does not work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What H.B. said +1

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object[]),typeof(CornerRadius))]
public class Multi : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new CornerRadius(Double.Parse("15"));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind making the 15 a string first and then to parse it again? (In the original code it was not a string)

Comment: oh,yes, it inconsistent results so I am confused .
but [attributes] is work.

Comment: As I said in the comment I think multi was returning a string but single was not.  I used that ctor for double to make typing clear.

Comment: @Blam: That is so *not* a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

[`Border.CornerRadius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius.aspx) is of type [`CornerRadius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius.aspx). Value converters should always return the right type for the property.

It is hard to tell why they behave differently, presumably there is no default value conversion using [type converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047.aspx) when using a multi-binding for some unexplained reason. If you were to dig into the source code you might find something but it probably won't be a pleasant journey.

Comment: I ran into the exact same observation as noticed by the OP. Could it be that default type converters are called after a value is converted using `IValueConverter`, but not after `IMultiValueConverter`? :/ I'm a bit baffled by this undocumented behavior.